# Pass dynamic click handler to Angular button

Tags: angular

I have the following Angular code in my component which works out from a service which buttons to display:

```
buttons: any;
private buttonsSubscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  this.buttonsSubscription = this.toolbarService.getButtons().subscribe((buttons: any) => {
    this.buttons = buttons;
  });

}
```

And then in my html I do the following:

```
<li *ngIf="buttons && buttons.length>0" class="buttons">
    <span *ngFor="let button of buttons">
        <a [routerLink]="[button.link]" title="{{button.text}}"><span>{{button.text}}</span></a>
    </span>
</li>
```

I'd like to include a button.onclick item, so some buttons will have Delete(), others may have Print().

How do I pass this to my html?

This is what I want to do (but obviously doesn't work):

```
<a (click)="{{button.onclick}}" title="{{button.text}}"><span>{{button.text}}</span></a>
```

Comment: (click)="button.onclick.bind(this)" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure something like this `[routerLink]="['/', button.link]"`

HTML:

```
<li *ngIf="buttons && buttons.length>0" class="buttons">
<span *ngFor="let button of buttons">
    <a [routerLink]="['/', button.link] title="{{button.text}}"><span>{{button.text}}</span></a>
</span>
```

if you want to add a button, then you can add a click event and call a method from TS to route it.

```
  <li *ngIf="buttons && buttons.length>0" class="buttons">
        <span *ngFor="let button of buttons">
        <button (click)="routeButton(button)">Click ME</button>
        </span>
    </li>
```

TS:

```
   routeButton(button){
this._router.navigateByUrl(button.link);
    }
```

Comment: I’d like my button to call a function like delete()

Comment: @RobbieMills then you can use the other approach that will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try making the following changes

**.ts**

```
let button = {
  // properties
  onClick : "onDelete";
}

onDelete(){
 console.log("Delete Click");
}
```

**.html**

```
<button (click)="this[button.onClick]">Click Me</button>
```

You can also check out this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cmcvg1)